# Entity Framework Linq query with IgnoreQueryFilters() does not work on lazyload property even with include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I have a table with users and use softdeletes on it.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserDomain>().Property<bool>("isDeleted");
modelBuilder.Entity<UserDomain>().HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<bool>(m, "isDeleted") == false);
```

So when a user is deleted the isDeleted column in the user table is switched to true. Every query that uses the table will ignore this user because it is deleted. So far so good.

Now if I want to get the users that are deleted I do something like:

```
dbContext.Users.IgnoreQueryFilters().Where(u => u.id == 1);
```

That also works. I get the user although it is deleted.

But now comes the problem. I have a table with invoices and they reference a user, with lazyloading.

For example:

```
class InvoiceDomain {
  int Id {get;set;}
  private UserDomain _user;
  virtual public UserDomain User { get => (_user != null) ? _user : _lazyLoader.Load(this, ref _user); set => _user = value; }

  private ILazyLoader _lazyLoader { get; set; }
  public InvoiceDomain(ILazyLoader lazyLoader) { _lazyLoader = lazyLoader; }

}
```

It is possible that I want to have an invoice but that the user attached to that invoice might be soft deleted. Still I want that user data.

So I thought: `dbContext.Invoices.IgnoreQueryFilters().include(i => i.User).Where(i => i.Id == 1);`

But that doesn't work. When I later on use `invoice.user` it is still `null`. How can I make sure that when loading the invoice, the soft deleted user is also loaded?

Comment: Could you try placing the `IgnoreQueryFilters` after the `Include` statement

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? What you are describing works in latest official 3.1